# What does 限り mean in this case?

Tags: meaning

> 当然ながら箱ごと盗むなんてのは、よほどのことでもない**限り**不可能だし

So from the context I kind of understand it:

> "Of course stealing that box is impossible"

or something along the line.

How does the 限り function here?

Comment: In your attempt you completely forgot about the part よほどのことでもない, didn't you? How would you understand it? Here the 限り means something in the line of "as long as", can you imagine what it does mean now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

限り means something like "the limit", as in the maximum amount or degree.

It can function like this:

> よほどのことがない**限り**不可能だ。

- To **the limit** that there is nothing really out of the ordinary, it's impossible.
- **So long as** there is nothing really out of the ordinary, it's impossible.

> 私が知る**限り**では不可能だ

- To **the limit** that I know, it's impossible.
- **As far as** I know, it's impossible.